# How to launch host browser from script inside docker container?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I am using Windows 10 with docker setup. I have the following `test_browser.py` script in ubuntu container which tries to launch web browser:

```py
import webbrowser

result = webbrowser.open("http://localhost:7070")

print(result)
```

If I try to run the above script inside container, it **fails** to open the url and prints `False` since there is no browser inside container.

[image: Testing script with CMD]

**Hence, I somehow want the script inside container to launch the url in host (windows) browser instead!**

Fortunately, I have found a way to achieve it using VSCode:
We can [attach](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container) to the running docker container and run the python script in its terminal. It will launch my windows chrome browser. Notice `True` output as well!

[image: Testing script with VSCode]

Since it is possible, I am looking for a way to do it without involving VSCode. Maybe some docker commands which can make it happen?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review the posting guidelines and reduce the text you have in your question to a single, definitively answerable question.

Comment: I have reworded my question, hopefully it is clear now